# Getting Error: IndexError: tuple index out of range, on applying ColumnTranformer on 1D array in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, indexing, tuples, transform

```
 import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd 
    dataset = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
    
    X= dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
    X= pd.DataFrame(X) 
    X.fillna(X.mean(), inplace=True) 
    Y= dataset.iloc[:,3].values
    
    
    from sklearn.preprocessing import  OneHotEncoder
    X= X.loc[:,:].values
    
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    columnTransformer = ColumnTransformer([('OneHot_X', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
    X= columnTransformer.fit_transform(X)
    
    
    *# when I am adding below lines, I m getting an error* 
    
    **columnTransformer_Y = ColumnTransformer([('OneHot1_Y', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
    Y= columnTransformer_Y.fit_transform(Y)**
```

I am trying to convert Y into two binary columns for categorization. When I am applying obj on Y, I am getting an error. But on X it's working well.

```
**Error:**

      File "C:\Users\ELCOT\Downloads\ML- Course\1.practise\ML_Preprocessing\code\data_preprocessing_my_template.py", line 41, in <module>
        Y= columnTransformer_Y.fit_transform(Y)

  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 516, in fit_transform
    self._validate_remainder(X)

  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 321, in _validate_remainder
    self._n_features = X.shape[1]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: check `print(Y)` - maybe you have something different then you expect. OR maybe if you have only one column in `Y` then you shouldn't use `remainder='passthrough'` because there will be no "remainder"

Comment: I have tried printing Y and I got the output : ['No' 'Yes' 'No' 'No' 'Yes' 'Yes' 'No' 'Yes' 'No' 'Yes']. And also, I have tried removing remainder= 'passthrough', but again I am getting the same error.

Comment: it seems you list or array with one dimention but `X.shape[1]` tries to set second dimension. maybe you should convert it to numpy array or DataFrame `[ ['No' 'Yes' 'No' 'No' 'Yes' 'Yes' 'No' 'Yes' 'No' 'Yes']  ]` or  `[ ['No'], ['Yes'], ['No'], ['No'], ['Yes'], ['Yes'], ['No'], ['Yes'], ['No'], ['Yes']  ]` . OR maybe you shouldn't use `.values` but keep it as `DataFrame`

Comment: `.iloc` can means it needs pandas `DataFrame`, not numpy `array`.

Comment: I have tried using `Y = np.asarray(Y)` to convert the array as a NumPy array. But Facing the same error. Tried using `.iloc` without  `.values` facing same error. Tried `Y=[Y]` to convert `['No' 'Yes' 'No' 'No' 'Yes' 'Yes' 'No' 'Yes' 'No' 'Yes']` as `[array(['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'], dtype=object)]`but When I am view `Y` I am getting first index only as output.                                                                               
`In [17]: Y
Out[17]: array([[1.]])`

Comment: I have tried                                                                                                                 `from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le= LabelEncoder()
Y= le.fit_transform(Y)`                                                                                                  
I have got desired output `Y
Out[20]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])`                                                                    
But could you please explain how Y was onehot encoded  ?

Comment: i don't understand why you convert it to `array`. Why not keep it as DataFrame like  `Y = pd.DataFrame(Y)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data so I create few fake columns.

I don't understand why you convert all to `numpy.array`. You could keep it as DataFrame and only `pd.Series` (`Y`) convert back to `pdDataFrame`

This code works without errors

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import  OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

#dataset = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

dataset = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'B': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'C': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'D': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'E': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
})
    
# X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values  # no need to convert to array
# X = pd.DataFrame(X)              # and later convert back to DataFrame

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1]          # keep it as DataFrame
X.fillna(X.mean(), inplace=True)  # work as DataFrame

# Y = dataset.iloc[:,3].values   # no need to convert to array

Y = dataset.iloc[:,3]  # this gives Series  
Y = pd.DataFrame(Y)    # convert Series to DataFrame

#X = X.loc[:,:].values  # no need to convert to array

columnTransformer_X = ColumnTransformer([('OneHot_X', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = columnTransformer_X.fit_transform(X)

columnTransformer_Y = ColumnTransformer([('OneHot_Y', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
Y = columnTransformer_Y.fit_transform(Y)
```